# GmMapFragment not showing maps on Android 5 (Lollipop)

Tags: android, android-maps-v2, android-5.0-lollipop

I have been unable to get maps to display in a GmMapFragment on Android 5.0. The control displays with zoom buttons etc but no actual map imagery. It appears to be unable to connect to the server to get the actual map.

Logcat gives me the following errors:

11-21 09:48:39.066: E/Google Maps Android API(16509): Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).

And lots of:

11-21 09:48:26.011: D/REQUEST(16509): Connection opened to:https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap/api
11-21 09:48:26.015: D/REQUEST(16509): Open Connection
11-21 09:48:39.055: D/REQUEST(16509): DRD(33): 62|15|147
11-21 09:48:39.056: D/REQUEST(16509): Close
11-21 09:48:39.056: D/REQUEST(16509): Error processing: com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.b.d@203c81d1 not retrying

Our API key is valid - the exact same app package displays maps just fine on an Android 4 device and has done since the feature was implemented months ago. I have tried updating our app to target API-21, and updating to latest google play services, both to no effect.

Anyone else seen this issue and/or been able to find a way round it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We have some trouble here with the Mapfragment as you described it too, but no server exceptions or something.

Our issue seems to be using different google-play-services verions... I coded it with Rev. 19, he just updated to Rev.21. It works when running the app with Rev. 19 but doesn't with Rev. 21.

Again, not the same exceptions etc, but we also have the "empty" mapfragment with the google sign and the controls.

Just trying to give you an approach.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We haven't changed our google play services lib version - I tried upgrading to see if it would solve the issue but it didn't so we've reverted now.